# Is there a way to calculate incremental area under the curve for each id subject?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm working in R and i'm trying to generate a data.frame with the incremental area under the curve of glucose values above baseline for each subject id (ID). In particular my dataset is like that:

```
ID  glucose Time
101 100     0
102 70      0
103 60      0
101 50      0.5
102 85      0.5
103 70      0.5
101 55      1
102 69      1
103 96      1
```

I'm using the function by Brouns et al (2005):

```
    auc.fn <- function(x,y) {
    auc <- ifelse(y[2] > y[1], (y[2]-y[1])*(x[2]-x[1])/2, 0)
    seg.type <- 0
    for (i in 3:length(x)) {
        if (y[i] >= y[1] & y[i-1] >= y[1]) {
            auc[i-1] <- (((y[i]-y[1])/2) + (y[i-1]-y[1])/2) * (x[i]-x[i-1])/2
            seg.type[i-1] <- 1
        } else if (y[i] >= y[1] & y[i-1] < y[1]) {
            auc[i-1] <- ((y[i]-y[1])^2/(y[i]-y[i-1])) * (x[i]-x[i-1])/2
            seg.type[i-1] <- 2
        } else if (y[i] < y[1] & y[i-1] >= y[1]) {
            auc[i-1] <- ((y[i-1]-y[1])^2/(y[i-1]-y[i])) * (x[i]-x[i-1])/2
            seg.type[i-1] <- 3
        } else if (y[i] < y[1] & y[i-1] < y[1]) {
            auc[i-1] <- 0
            seg.type[i-1] <- 4
        } else {
            # The above cases are exhaustive, so this should never happpen
            return(cat("i:", i, "Error: No condition met\n"))
        }
    }
    return(list(auc=sum(auc), segments=auc, seg.type=seg.type))
}
```

However, this function returns only the whole AUC value. How can i change the function in order to have for each id subject an AUC value?
Many thanks

Comment: To be clear, does `auc.fn` take any two vectors `x` and `y` of equal length `n`, treat {(`x[1]`, `y[1]`), (`x[2]`, `y[2]`), ..., (`x[n]`, `y[n]`)} as points generated by  = (), and calculate the area under the curve (among other info) for each line segment connecting those points?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes in this case x = Time, y= glucose to AUC above baseline values overtime.

Comment: And just to check: you want to isolate each `ID` as a series over time?  That is, you want to plot each `ID` on a separate graph — in isolation — and then calculate the AUC for each of those graphs?  My [current solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68412351) does exactly that.

Comment: However, if the _"baseline values"_ are interdependent — calculated in the context of the entire dataset — you'll need to expand on that in your question, and this answer won't apply.  Frankly, I'm surprised by the `$auc` of `0` for the `ID` of `101`, so maybe there's more here than meets the eye...

Comment: Anyway, let me know if the solution works for you!  :)

Comment: It works very well thanks so much :-) To reply to your doubt "Why the 101 has AUC=0", this happens because it only calculate positive values. If in the future i will have some subjects with missing values, what should i do? Thanks again :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Would you be so kind as to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and upvote my answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Just saw this: _"If in the future i will have some subjects with missing values, what should i do?"_  I'm not sure what results you'd want in this situation. If a subject (`ID` of `104`) has a missing observation (at `Time` of `0.5`), would you want the `104` curve to be the line segment, from (`0.0`, `glucose[1]`) to (`1.0`, `glucose[3]`), which "skips" the missing value? As long as you have enough observations (3?), to satisfy `auc.fn()`, I think this solution would still work.  If not, then `auc.fn()` needs to be rewritten to meaningfully handle situations where `x` and `y` are too short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `base` solution, made cleaner by the pipe operator `%>%` (originally from `magrittr`).

Given a dataset `my_dataset`

```
my_dataset <- structure(list(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 101, 102, 103, 101, 102, 103),
                             glucose = c(100, 70, 60, 50, 85, 70, 55, 69, 96),
                             Time = c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1)),
                        row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

like the sample you provided

```
   ID glucose Time
1 101     100  0.0
2 102      70  0.0
3 103      60  0.0
4 101      50  0.5
5 102      85  0.5
6 103      70  0.5
7 101      55  1.0
8 102      69  1.0
9 103      96  1.0
```

we can `split()` the dataset by `ID` and `sapply()` your specialized function `auc.fn` to each split chunk:

```
library(magrittr)

# ...
# Code to define the function 'auc.fn()' and to generate your dataset 'my_dataset'.
# ...

results <- my_dataset %>%
  split(.$ID) %>%
  sapply(FUN = function(df){auc.fn(x = df$Time, y = df$glucose)}, simplify = FALSE)
```

This yields the following `list` for `results`, named by `ID`:

```
$`101`
$`101`$auc
[1] 0

$`101`$segments
[1] 0 0

$`101`$seg.type
[1] 0 4


$`102`
$`102`$auc
[1] 7.265625

$`102`$segments
[1] 3.750000 3.515625

$`102`$seg.type
[1] 0 3


$`103`
$`103`$auc
[1] 8.25

$`103`$segments
[1] 2.50 5.75

$`103`$seg.type
[1] 0 1
```

If you want *only* the AUC for each `ID`, simply replace that last line with

```
  sapply(FUN = function(df){auc.fn(x = df$Time, y = df$glucose)$auc}, simplify = TRUE)
```

to get this named vector for `results`:

```
     101      102      103 
0.000000 7.265625 8.250000
```